# Touch interface in android phones

Tags: terminology

What are the dots used for horizontal scrolling called? These light up to show what screen the user is on.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this got voted down. It is a straight forward question with a range of demonstrable concrete answers. Is that the problem? Is it not subjective enough for UX? +1 for equilibrium.

Comment: @Gusdor The downvote item itself (on the tooltip) states that the reason for downvoting would be "*..does not show any research effort*" which this question does not, so it is likely that is the reason for the downvote. Also, there is no examples of where this is used, what purpose they OP has for asking it. It's just a one-liner where somewhere like Google should be the first port of call.

Comment: @JonW I can accept that.

Comment: This isn't really specific to android. Most web sites have page indicators similar to this (with numbers instead of circles) and this specific picture is from iOS (first result I found for page indicator in image search).

Comment: @DannyVarod you're right. _actually_ these dots are not "android-ish" at all! Check the design guide - you won't find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the developers in my company referred it as "**android pagination indicator**" or "**Page Indicator**"

you can see some example over here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486218/android-added-circle-indicator-to-viewpager

http://viewpagerindicator.com/

you can also check some android patterns over here: http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/horizontal-scrolling-page-indicators

Comment: Thanks for all the help.Actually, I new to the world of user interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if they have a formal name but I would refer to these as **page indicators**.

You can compare this to a tabbed view quite nicely (the difference is that you navigate by swiping). If you are using this idiom, the dots are now the **tab headers**.

Comment: "page indicator" seems to be a commonly used term for this: https://www.google.com/search?q=page+indicator&newwindow=1&safe=off&espv=210&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=qHVmUvmLHYWR7AbC6IHQCw&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1236&bih=761

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to these as "**pagination buttons**". The content is [paginated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination), and these are buttons which can be used to move between each page. These usually (but not always) have an active state when the page they link to is the currently visible page.